# como identificar e eliminar colunas com caracteres e fator no R

Tags: r

Tenho um data.frame com varias colunas com diferentes dados, inteiros, numéricos, caractere e fator.

Preciso de realizar uma matriz de correlação com esses dados, mas o R so consegue realizar a correlação com dados numéricos(int e dbl).

Gostaria de separar somente os dados numéricos(int e dbl) para fazer a correlação. como poderia fazer isto?

exemplo dos meus dados.

```
j<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
k<-c(50,2,042,3658,14,3586,324,24,352,217)
y<-c('aaa','bbb','ccc','ccc','ddd','eee','eee','bbb','aaa','aaa')
x<-c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)
z<-c("segunda","terça","quarta","segunda","sexta","quinta","quinta","sexta","quarta","terça")#fator

df<-data.frame(g,j,k,y,x,z)

view(df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a função `select_if` do `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

j<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
k<-c(50,2,042,3658,14,3586,324,24,352,217)
y<-c('aaa','bbb','ccc','ccc','ddd','eee','eee','bbb','aaa','aaa')
x<-c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)
z<-c("segunda","terça","quarta","segunda","sexta","quinta","quinta","sexta","quarta","terça")#fator

df<-data.frame(j,k,y,x,z)

df %>%
  select_if(is.numeric) %>%
  cor()
#>             j           k
#> j  1.00000000 -0.03185042
#> k -0.03185042  1.00000000
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Olá @Marcus Nunes testei aqui o comando e funcionou para todo o exemplo. Mas tive um problema ao aplicar no meu df real. Sei que não especifiquei na pergunta, mas tenho uma coluna da classe "list" que é um a sf() de um polígono do estado. Os resultado ficaram somente com as colunas "numeric" e "list". tentei aplicar o comando select(- ) na coluna lista e outras dicas da web, mas nao resolveu. Enfim continuo sem conseguir fazer a correlação por causa dessa list. será que posso editar a pergunta ou abrir uma nova?

Comment: Recomendo abrir uma nova pergunta, pois a pergunta original foi respondida.

Answer (score 1):

Pode aplicar `is.numeric` às colunas e usar o vetor lógico resultante para indexar o *data.frame*:

```
df[sapply(df, is.numeric)]
#>     j    k
#> 1   1   50
#> 2   2    2
#> 3   3   42
#> 4   4 3658
#> 5   5   14
#> 6   6 3586
#> 7   7  324
#> 8   8   24
#> 9   9  352
#> 10 10  217
```

Não é seu caso, para para ficar registrado: se quiser excluir algumas classes específicas, pode usar o operador de negação (`!`) em conjunto com múltiplas comparações `is.*`:

```
df[!sapply(df, function(x) is.factor(x) | is.character(x))]
#>     j    k     x
#> 1   1   50  TRUE
#> 2   2    2 FALSE
#> 3   3   42  TRUE
#> 4   4 3658 FALSE
#> 5   5   14  TRUE
#> 6   6 3586 FALSE
#> 7   7  324  TRUE
#> 8   8   24 FALSE
#> 9   9  352  TRUE
#> 10 10  217 FALSE
```