# como excluir uma coluna da classe tipo "list" no R

Tags: r

Tenho um data.frame no qual preciso realizar uma matriz de correlação.

Já separei os dados numéricos pelo comando `select_if(is.numeric)` como sugerido pelo colega no [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/488186/como-identificar-e-eliminar-colunas-com-caracteres-e-fator-no-r).

Entretanto, no meu data.frame ainda há um dado com classe diferente de "numeric", ou seja, há uma coluna da classe `list`, que é um a `sf()` de um polígono do estado. Tentei aplicar o comando `select(- )` na coluna `list` e também o comando `distinct_at(vars(-))` e outras dicas da web, mas não resolveu. Enfim continuo sem conseguir fazer a correlação por causa dessa `list`.

infelizmente nao consigo reproduzir um exemplo de `list` aqui, mas ha uma imagem de parte do meu df.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema pode ser resolvido em R base ou com o pacote `dplyr`, que é o que a pergunta parece querer.

Vou usar esta base exemplo:

```
dados <- data.frame(a = 1:3, 
                    b = I(list(1,1:2,1:3)), 
                    c = letters[1:3])
dados
#  a       b c
#1 1       1 a
#2 2    1, 2 b
#3 3 1, 2, 3 c
```

## 1. R base

Primeiro determina-se quais as colunas de classe `"numeric"` e depois extraem-se essas colunas.

```
j <- sapply(dados, is.numeric)
j
#    a     b     c 
# TRUE FALSE FALSE 

dados[j]
#  a
#1 1
#2 2
#3 3
```

Para remover só as colunas de classe `"list"`, faz-se de forma análoga mas negando o índice lógico.

```
i <- sapply(dados, is.list)
dados[!i]
#  a c
#1 1 a
#2 2 b
#3 3 c
```

## 2. Pacote `dplyr`

Em vez de `select_if`, usar `select(where(.))`.

```
library(dplyr)

dados %>%
  select(where(is.numeric))
#  a
#1 1
#2 2
#3 3
```

Comment: olá @Rui Barradas. Testei as soluções, porem não obtive êxito em remover as "list" do meu data frame. A titulo de esclarecimento eu usei o pacote GEOBR para criar esse data.frame. Vejo que a solução que vc colocou funciona para remover a "list" do dataframe exemplo, mas no meu caso não deu certo. Ao usar o `sapply`, ele cria uma nova coluna com valores False e True. O comando `select(where(is.numeric))` de fato separa apenas os dados numeric, mas a coluna `geom` com a `list` ainda permanece, eu usaria esse comando em outra situação. Mas infelizmente no meu caso ainda nao deu certo.

Comment: @wesleysc352 Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(dados)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(dados, 20))`?

Comment: ola @Rui Barradas, como o meu df tem uma `list` com  `sf()` ele vai ficar enorme, mas vou colocar

Comment: ola @Rui Barradas eu tentei fazer dput(head(dados, 1)), mas o StackOverflow so permite 30mil caracteres e o meu deu 34mil. Como eu disse, eu usei o GEOBR para criar meu df, esse pacote pega todas as coordenadas do limite de um município e coloca dentro do df em formato de `list`.

Comment: @wesleysc352 Então poste a saída de `str(dados)`, por favor. Ou, ainda melhor, código que permita criar uma base com estrutura semelhante mas não necessáriamente com o mesmo tamanho. (34 mil é demais, é possível *muito* mais pequena?)

Comment: ola faz um tempinho que abri a pergunta, mas eu consegui resolver o problema de uma forma muito simples nao sei se aplica ao demais caso: `df2<-df %>% st_set_geometry (NULL)` foi capaz de remover as colunas do tipo `list`